# Two dates difference in SpagoBI Studio javascript code?

Tags: spagobi

I want to know the format to get the number of days between two dates in spagoBI studio?
I have  StartDate and EndDate and I want to know the Number of days between these dates.

Comment: row["ENDDATE"]-row["STARTDATE"] and i am getting 0 for all rows

Comment: row["ENDDATE"]?? is there any data table which has been bind to a Data set? if you have a table, try `row[0]`. It returns number of rows in the table.If not create dataset as below
`select count(*) from your_table where date between [STARTDATE] and [ENDDATE] `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question to ask is what type of document are you creating in SpagoBI studio? Is it a BIRT or Jasper Report? It is a chart ?  Almost everything coming in from a SpagoBI dataset is treated as a String.

If you were using JavaScript in a BIRT report, you would need to covert those ENDDATE And STARTDATE row values to equivalent JavaScript date  objects before performing calculations .

What about modifying the dataset query to perform the date difference in SQL and pass that back as a column?

Comment: thanks for your reply It is a birt report. Yes it is the correct way to work on the dataset query. i need to find out the query for the columns where STARTDATE,ENDDATE  and Sales,,are given and need to find out the sales per month between the dates. please let me know the query.

Comment: If you want to do the diff between dates, calculated in in SQL, it will be dependent on which database your using . Each database server provides its own date manipulation functions . What is the schema for the table ?

Comment: the schema name is dbo and i am using sql server 2005.                         'Select startdate, enddate,datediff(day, startdate, enddate)from data'        i am using this query to know the date difference between two dates but i need to find days as per month between the two dates

Comment: 2015-06-21 00:00:00.000      2015-07-21 00:00:00.000      30days
2015-06-30 00:00:00.000      2015-07-30 00:00:00.000      30days
                        I m getting this output but i wish to get the output as                                         2015-06-21 00:00:00.000 2015-08-21 00:00:00.000 30 June 10  july 31 august 21       and this is for two different columns not only for two date difference

Comment: SpagoBI datasets and BIRT usually need to have a fixed set of columns . Based on the sample data, it illustrates showing a potentially dynamic number of columns, three for each month that the start to end range .  You may run into a problem there if you want to run the report for more than a set number of months.  Search on stack overflow or GOOG for how to determine number of days in a month via SQL server tsql. You can use PIVOT to demoralize the days-in-a-month data and show it in one row .

Comment: yeah m trying to do with sql query not with spagoBI but i am not able to build the one :(